# Refreshing DataGridView After Editing a Record

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView bound to a datatable which comes from an SQL Server database.

When the user edits a record my update statement changes the field datetimemodified to reflect the last date and time the record was edited (as stored procedure). The new value for datetimemodified is not brought into my DataGridView.

1) How do I refresh a DataGridView bound to a DataTable? Is there any way to refresh or resync only records that have changed instead of the entire DataTable? (Note: my update statement is working fine. I'm only wondering about refreshing the DataGridView.)

2) Would it be better to change the value of DateTimeModified on the client side so that I can avoid a refresh (assuming that this is the only reason I need to refresh the data)?

Answer (score 0):

```
fnDraw
```

function will help you

```
oTable.fnDraw();
```

if you using ajax to edit. you can call this function in ajax success

Comment: I failed to mention that this is a winforms application. Does your answer work for this?

Comment: oh! i don't have idea about that

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you described requires to use Domain Objects that implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface. This will allow any change in Domain object to be propagated back in UI. use Domain object with BindingList. Datatables provide flexible but inefficient approach of data-binding. You may find following resource helpful.

[How to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

[Datatable vs BindingList](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2007/04/04/datatable-vs-bindinglist-t.aspx)